# Splitting large dataframe into list of smaller pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    y  gdp  cap
0   1    2    5
1   2    3    9
2   8    7    2
3   3    4    7
4   6    7    7
```

Is there a way I can split it up into a list of pandas dataframes each with 1 row and same header as this big dataframe? I can loop over it ofcourse, but is there a more pythonic soln?

The use case is:

```
with Pool(processes=5) as p:
    p.starmap(parallel_func, list(single_row_of_dataframe))
```

Comment: Looping is Pythonic.

Comment: Wait, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this `mp.Pool`??? I am skeptical that this approach will yield performance improvements over serially processing the data-frame. Each chunk is copied and pickled in the parent process, and deserialized by the child process. That's a huge amount of overhead. Especially considering you are using perhaps the least-compact way of doing this possible: a list of individual data-frames!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, the parallel_func function takes several seconds for each row. So as long as the overhead is low enough compared to parallel_func, it should be a net gain.

Comment: I think perhaps the best question is what exactly is `parallel_func` doing that it takes several seconds per row?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, it is a bunch of mathematical calculations (Fast fourier transforms etc.) that are time-consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`np.split`

```
for i in np.arange(1, len(df))):
     print(i, '\n')

   y  gdp  cap
0  1    2    5 

   y  gdp  cap
1  2    3    9 

   y  gdp  cap
2  8    7    2 

   y  gdp  cap
3  3    4    7 

   y  gdp  cap
4  6    7    7
```

If your index is monotonic, you can use that to split:

```
for i in np.split(df, df.index[1:]):
    print(i, '\n')
```

Note that `np.split`, at its heart, is a loop implementation, so you aren't really escaping the iteration.

```
splits = np.split(df, df.index[1:])
```

---

**Option 2**
Looping over `df.index` and calling `loc`:

```
splits = [df.loc[[i]] for i in df.index]
```

---

Fleshing out a discussion in the comments here - if you're looking to do some sort of parallelisation, look into `dask` dataframes. Don't try and implement your own parallelisation with `Pool`, you'll actually suffer performance drops.

Comment: It's worth noting that parallel processing of individual rows in pure Python code is likely to still be *much* slower than single-threaded processing through code that takes better advantage of pandas/numpy C bindings. So while this will work it is *very* unlikely to actually help your performance to process each row individually.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield Well said. For parallel processing, `dask` would be better suited.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield yes, well, the OP is asking for a *list* of *single-rowed* data-frames. Their are various ways to achieve this, none of which will be amenable to parallelization. I smell an XY problem

Answer (score 3):

Or You can using `//` and `groupby`, I split the dataframe by 3 , you can change the number you need

```
[df1 for _,df1 in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3)]
Out[356]: 
[   y  gdp  cap
 0  1    2    5
 1  2    3    9
 2  8    7    2,    y  gdp  cap
 3  3    4    7
 4  6    7    7]
```